# jquery animate: change the element's opacity one by one

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, opacity

Any idea how to animate the opacity of each certain element one by one up to 16 targets/ elements only?

This will change the opacity of the elements all together,

```
$('.block-item').animate({
        opacity:0
    },500);
```

Have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VS8tQ/).

But I want the opacity to change one after another. and this will stop when it reaches the 16th element.

Here is the html,

```
<div id="parent_container">

<div class="block-item">1</div>
<div class="block-item">2</div>
<div class="block-item">3</div>
<div class="block-item">4</div>
<div class="block-item">5</div>
<div class="block-item">6</div>
<div class="block-item">7</div>
<div class="block-item">8</div>
<div class="block-item">9</div>
<div class="block-item">10</div>
<div class="block-item">11</div>
<div class="block-item">12</div>
<div class="block-item">13</div>
<div class="block-item">14</div>
<div class="block-item">15</div>
<div class="block-item">16</div>
<div class="block-item">17</div>
<div class="block-item">18</div>

</div>
```

I came out this function but it crashes any browser on it,

```
function opacity_test(index)
{
    $('.block-item').eq( index ).animate({
        opacity:0
    },500);

    setInterval( function() {
        opacity_test(index + 1);
    }, 1000 );
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
var delay = 0;
$('.block-item:lt(16)').each(function(){ 
               //^^ do for every instance less than the 16th (starting at 0)
    $(this).delay(delay).animate({
        opacity:0
    },500);
    delay += 500;
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/VS8tQ/3/

Answer (score 9):

You can use the "completion callback" of `.animate()` to start the next fade:

```
function fade(index) {
    $('.block-item').eq(index).animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, function() {
        // on completion, recursively call myself
        // against the next element
        if (index < 15) {
            fade(index + 1);
        }
    })
}

fade(0);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/3DuTG/

Comment: @alnitak, did not see that there.. hmmmm

Comment: @Neal FWIW your solution could probably be fixed just by putting `.lt(16)` before the `.each()` call.

Comment: @alnitak hmm ill add that to my answer as an option.

Comment: @Neal - ah, that's one of the selectors that isn't also available as a function :(

Comment: @alnitak, i added it to the selector

Answer (score 4):

An option using the callback, and to stop when it reaches the 16th element you can use `.index()`

```
var f = function($current) {
    $current.animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, function() {
        if ($current.next(".block-item").index() < 15) {
            f($current.next(".block-item"));
        }
    });
};

f($(".block-item:first"));
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/VS8tQ/2/)**